# Errors were encountered loading footprints: kicad_plugin.cpp : FootprintEnumerate() : line 1786

Tags: linux, kicad, footprint

I am newbie in working with KiCad So for first time i tried to generate footprint of one negetive voltage source from [here](http://www.theorycircuit.com/negative-voltage-generator-circuit/) and [here](http://www.csgnetwork.com/ne555c1.html):
[image]
And the  Sketch is like this :
[image]

button and i get this error in my linux LMDE like this:
[image]

```
Errors were encountered loading footprints:
IO_ERROR: footprint library path '/usr/share/kicad/modules//Resistors_THT.pretty' does not exist from /build/kicad-OLDpkC/kicad-4.0.5+dfsg1/pcbnew/kicad_plugin.cpp : FootprintEnumerate() : line 1786
IO_ERROR: footprint library path '/usr/share/kicad/modules//Displays.pretty' does not exist from /build/kicad-OLDpkC/kicad-4.0.5+dfsg1/pcbnew/kicad_plugin.cpp : FootprintEnumerate() : line 1786
IO_ERROR: footprint library path '/usr/share/kicad/modules//Buttons_Switches_THT.pretty' does not exist from /build/kicad-OLDpkC/kicad-4.0.5+dfsg1/pcbnew/kicad_plugin.cpp : FootprintEnumerate() : line 1786
IO_ERROR: footprint library path '/usr/share/kicad/modules//Connectors_WAGO.pretty' does not exist from /build/kicad-OLDpkC/kicad-4.0.5+dfsg1/pcbnew/kicad_plugin.cpp : FootprintEnumerate() : line 1786
IO_ERROR: footprint library path '/usr/share/kicad/modules//Connectors.pretty' does not exist from /build/kicad-OLDpkC/kicad-4.0.5+dfsg1/pcbnew/kicad_plugin.cpp : FootprintEnumerate() : line 1786
IO_ERROR: footprint library path '/usr/share/kicad/modules//Capacitors_THT.pretty' does not exist from /build/kicad-OLDpkC/kicad-4.0.5+dfsg1/pcbnew/kicad_plugin.cpp : FootprintEnumerate() : line 1786
IO_ERROR: footprint library path '/usr/share/kicad/modules//Diodes_THT.pretty' does not exist from /build/kicad-OLDpkC/kicad-4.0.5+dfsg1/pcbnew/kicad_plugin.cpp : FootprintEnumerate() : line 1786
IO_ERROR: footprint library path '/usr/share/kicad/modules//Relays_THT.pretty' does not exist from /build/kicad-OLDpkC/kicad-4.0.5+dfsg1/pcbnew/kicad_plugin.cpp : FootprintEnumerate() : line 1786
IO_ERROR: footprint library path '/usr/share/kicad/modules//Connectors_Mini-Universal.pretty' does not exist from /build/kicad-OLDpkC/kicad-4.0.5+dfsg1/pcbnew/kicad_plugin.cpp : FootprintEnumerate() : line 1786
IO_ERROR: footprint library path '/usr/share/kicad/modules//Connectors_Terminal_Blocks.pretty' does not exist from /build/kicad-OLDpkC/kicad-4.0.5+dfsg1/pcbnew/kicad_plugin.cpp : FootprintEnumerate() : line 1786
```

i have also googled it and found some information like this ([Error Encountered IO_ERROR: Footprint library path
)](https://forum.kicad.info/t/error-encountered-io-error-footprint-library-path/4424) :

> I have seen this error myself. So far on the Windows version at work.
>   It is (nor can it be) connected to the Internet.
>
> Reply
>
> bobc Nov '16 The method kicad_plugin.cpp:FootprintEnumerate() is
>   designed to load from a local folder, not a URL, so it will throw an
>   error if it gets a URL.
>
> I guess that could happen if you have a footprint table entry set to
>   KiCad when it should be Github, or there is a bug in the cache
>   handling in KiCad.

But i don't get any idea for solving it!!!

Also from  [installation KiCad  for linux MINT](http://kicad-pcb.org/download/linux-mint/) in this site i get this  suggestion:

> If you prefer to use the shell, you can enter these commands into a
>   terminal:
>
> sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:js-reynaud/kicad-5.1 sudo apt update
>   sudo apt install --install-suggests kicad This will perform a full
>   installation of KiCad. If you don’t want to install all packages you
>   can use:
>
> sudo apt install kicad If you don’t do a "full installation" you
>   should be interested to install also:
>
> kicad-libraries: a virtual package that will recommend you to install
>   footprints, symbols, templates and 3D
>
> kicad-symbols, kicad-templates, kicad-footprints, kicad-packages3d: if
>   you want to manually select what library to install.

but i can not install this command:

```
sudo apt install --install-suggests kicad-libraries
```

i get this error:

```
so@notebook:~$ sudo apt install --install-suggests kicad-libraries
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kicad-libraries
```

i also can not install new version byt this codes:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:js-reynaud/kicad-5
```

i get this error:

```
so@notebook:~$ sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:js-reynaud/kicad-5

Adding PPAs is not supported
```

So is there any what to install it by linux command code or i must reinstall it or add footprint libraries manually?

[This question](https://forum.kicad.info/t/errors-were-encountered-loading-footprints-kicad-plugin-cpp-footprintenumerate-line-1786/19513) links asked at kicad furom.

Please help regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the instructions are for Linux MINT.  You are running LMDE.  To quote from the [LMDE announcement](https://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=3232):

> LMDE is less mainstream than Linux Mint, it has a much smaller user
>   base, it is not compatible with PPAs, and it lacks a few features.
>   That makes it a bit harder to use and harder to find help for, so it
>   is not recommended for novice users.

The PPAs are derived from Ubuntu. Since LMDE is derived from Debian, you can't use them safely.

Neither Mint nor LMDE are [officially supported distributions](http://kicad-pcb.org/help/system-requirements/#_gnulinux) by the KiCad Project.  If you plan on using KiCad for working with circuits, it may be advisable to use one of the supported distributions.

You may be able to use one of the Debian packages with LMDE but since there is no actual maintainer for the distribution, there may be many problems with this path.

If you just want the libraries, you should use:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --install-suggests kicad
```

Comment: Is it anyway to change the LMDE Linux to better distribution without losing my installed packages on it?

Comment: I can't say for certain.  If I were doing that, I would run `dpkg --get-selections` and save the output to a file, then install those packages in the new distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You did not include all the information you have here in the forum post (the screenshots are missing) which means i did miss that you run on v4.

If kicad itself runs and you only have trouble installing libs then you can always do this manually. However this is a bit harder with version 4 than with version 5.

To be honest at this point in time i would not install the normal v4 libs anyways but use the backported v5 libs. (https://github.com/KiCad/kicad-footprints/releases/tag/v4-backport-5.0.0, https://github.com/KiCad/kicad-symbols/releases/tag/v4-backport-5.0.0)

Installation of footprint libs is explained here (including details on how to download them.): https://forum.kicad.info/t/how-can-i-install-a-specific-version-of-the-footprint-library/9269

---

The symbol side is made harder in v4 as there is no library table in kicad 4 for symbols. The "easiest" option would be to place the symbols (from the zip file linked in the forum post or the v5 backport linked above) somewhere logical and manually add them to a personal "starter" project (adding libs is done in the symbol editor -> properties -> component libs or similar it is quite a while since i last worked with v4).  Make sure to use absolute file paths instead of relative (copying the file around would not work otherwise)

You then copy that project instead of using kicads "new project" functionality. (You only need the .pro file as it is the file containing the list of libraries. This file can be renamed safely to fit your desired name for the new project.)

If you want to do it properly then you would need to include your self installed libs in the kicad template project. It is normally found in /usr/share/kicad/templates (or similar, again i do not fully remember how it was done in v4). See https://forum.kicad.info/t/where-are-the-momentary-bush-button-switches-located/5695/18 for details (towards the end, i had confused footprints and symbols at the beginning of that post)

Comment: I wan to add the information but the KiCad  forum on don't let to add more two link or two photos into my post, so I removed this information.

Comment: yes new users are a bit restricted (default discord behaviour) but if you read a few posts then you should be promoted to the next rank which allows unlimited uploads and links.